# Liouville's Theorem Derivative solving?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I believe this is a Liouville's Theorem problem, but I am unsure as to how to solve it.

> Assume that $|f(z)|< |z^2 + 3z +1|$ for all $z$, and that $f(1) = 2$. Evaluate $f '(2)$, and explain your answer.

Comment: Consider $f(z)/(z^2+3z+1)$.

Comment: Do I define g(z) as the limit as z-->0 of f(z)/(z^ 2 +3z+1) and solve for where g(z) is constant?

Comment: $|f(z)|< |z^2 + 3z +1|$ cannot be true for all $z$ because $z^2 + 3z +1$ has zeros in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the closure of this question: The OP has included some beginning thoughts on the problem, mentioning specifically Liouville's theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite correct that this is a Liouville's theorem problem. The function

$$g(z) := \frac{f(z)}{z^2 + 3z + 1}$$

(where $z^2 + 3z + 1 \ne 0$) is bounded and has an analytic extension to all of $\mathbb{C}$; hence, it is constant. This implies that $f(z)$ is a scalar multiple of $z^2 + 3z + 1$, and the fact that $f(1) = 2$ tells you what that multiple is. Now computing the derivative is an elementary calculation.

---

As a remark, it's a nice result that whenever $f$ and $g$ are analytic functions so that there is a constant $c$ with $|f(z)| \le c |g(z)|$ for all $z$, $f$ and $g$ are multiples of each other.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. With that being said, I found the constant to be 2 and the answer for f '(2) to be 14.

Comment: @user299020 I think your constant is incorrect.

Comment: You're right. I redid it and I got my constant to be 2/5 and the answer for f '(2) to be 14/5.

Comment: @user299020 Yes.